# Convert Money to Text in PHP

Tags: php, string, currency, formatting

I need to convert say $89.50 to Eighty-Nine Dollars and Fifty Cents using PHP.  Is there a function I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: I have a similar question, how do i "Convert PHP to Money" :)
is there any method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a start for you. It's a recursive function I wrote a while back (part of solving a [Project Euler problem 17](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=17)) that converts numbers to letters... It can handle some pretty big numbers ;)

All you need to do is add the dollars and cents components and modify according to need. So basically you'd have to call the function once for the dollar amount and once for the cents component. I don't think there's a native PHP funciton for this. You'd have to use a library (like Pear) function.

(You can see [the function in action)](http://peter-ajtai.com/examples/numbers.php):

```
<?php
function translateToWords($number) 
{
/*****
     * A recursive function to turn digits into words
     * Numbers must be integers from -999,999,999,999 to 999,999,999,999 inclussive.    
     *
     *  (C) 2010 Peter Ajtai
     *    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
     *    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
     *    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
     *    (at your option) any later version.
     *
     *    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
     *    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
     *    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
     *    GNU General Public License for more details.
     *
     *    See the GNU General Public License: <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
     *
     */
    // zero is a special case, it cause problems even with typecasting if we don't deal with it here
    $max_size = pow(10,18);
    if (!$number) return "zero";
    if (is_int($number) && $number < abs($max_size)) 
    {            
        switch ($number) 
        {
            // set up some rules for converting digits to words
            case $number < 0:
                $prefix = "negative";
                $suffix = translateToWords(-1*$number);
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;
                break;
            case 1:
                $string = "one";
                break;
            case 2:
                $string = "two";
                break;
            case 3:
                $string = "three";
                break;
            case 4: 
                $string = "four";
                break;
            case 5:
                $string = "five";
                break;
            case 6:
                $string = "six";
                break;
            case 7:
                $string = "seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                $string = "eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                $string = "nine";
                break;                
            case 10:
                $string = "ten";
                break;            
            case 11:
                $string = "eleven";
                break;            
            case 12:
                $string = "twelve";
                break;            
            case 13:
                $string = "thirteen";
                break;            
            // fourteen handled later
            case 15:
                $string = "fifteen";
                break;            
            case $number < 20:
                $string = translateToWords($number%10);
                // eighteen only has one "t"
                if ($number == 18)
                {
                $suffix = "een";
                } else 
                {
                $suffix = "teen";
                }
                $string .= $suffix;
                break;            
            case 20:
                $string = "twenty";
                break;            
            case 30:
                $string = "thirty";
                break;            
            case 40:
                $string = "forty";
                break;            
            case 50:
                $string = "fifty";
                break;            
            case 60:
                $string = "sixty";
                break;            
            case 70:
                $string = "seventy";
                break;            
            case 80:
                $string = "eighty";
                break;            
            case 90:
                $string = "ninety";
                break;                
            case $number < 100:
                $prefix = translateToWords($number-$number%10);
                $suffix = translateToWords($number%10);
                $string = $prefix . "-" . $suffix;
                break;
            // handles all number 100 to 999
            case $number < pow(10,3):                    
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,2)))) . " hundred";
                if ($number%pow(10,2)) $suffix = " and " . translateToWords($number%pow(10,2));
                $string = $prefix . $suffix;
                break;
            case $number < pow(10,6):
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,3)))) . " thousand";
                if ($number%pow(10,3)) $suffix = translateToWords($number%pow(10,3));
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;
                break;
            case $number < pow(10,9):
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,6)))) . " million";
                if ($number%pow(10,6)) $suffix = translateToWords($number%pow(10,6));
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;
                break;                    
            case $number < pow(10,12):
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,9)))) . " billion";
                if ($number%pow(10,9)) $suffix = translateToWords($number%pow(10,9));
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;    
                break;
            case $number < pow(10,15):
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,12)))) . " trillion";
                if ($number%pow(10,12)) $suffix = translateToWords($number%pow(10,12));
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;    
                break;        
            // Be careful not to pass default formatted numbers in the quadrillions+ into this function
            // Default formatting is float and causes errors
            case $number < pow(10,18):
                // floor return a float not an integer
                $prefix = translateToWords(intval(floor($number/pow(10,15)))) . " quadrillion";
                if ($number%pow(10,15)) $suffix = translateToWords($number%pow(10,15));
                $string = $prefix . " " . $suffix;    
                break;                    
        }
    } else
    {
        echo "ERROR with - $number<br/> Number must be an integer between -" . number_format($max_size, 0, ".", ",") . " and " . number_format($max_size, 0, ".", ",") . " exclussive.";
    }
    return $string;    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

http://pear.php.net/package-info.php?package=Numbers_Words

Because clearly "no" wasn't the right answer to this question.

> » Summary
>
> The PEAR Numbers_Words
>   package provides methods for spelling
>   numerals in words.

Comment: Oh come on. "No." is so succinct and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

No, I believe you need to write one yourself. It's quite straightforward to implement but there are a bunch of corner cases you'll need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such function in PHP. The easiest is if you download some code [from the internet](http://www.codediesel.com/data/number-to-text-conversion/).