# How to convert decimal number to words (money format) using PHP?

Tags: php, currency, currency-formatting

I just need a little help here. Because I am creating a code for converting decimals to Money format in words. For example if

*I have this number*

**'2143.45'**

*the output should be*

**'two thousand one hundred forty three and forty-five cents'**

I found a code like this but I don't have an idea how to include cents.

```
<?php

function convertNumber($number)
{
    list($integer, $fraction) = explode(".", (string) $number);

    $output = "";

    if ($integer{0} == "-")
    {
        $output = "negative ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "-");
    }
    else if ($integer{0} == "+")
    {
        $output = "positive ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "+");
    }

    if ($integer{0} == "0")
    {
        $output .= "zero";
    }
    else
    {
        $integer = str_pad($integer, 36, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $group   = rtrim(chunk_split($integer, 3, " "), " ");
        $groups  = explode(" ", $group);

        $groups2 = array();
        foreach ($groups as $g)
        {
            $groups2[] = convertThreeDigit($g{0}, $g{1}, $g{2});
        }

        for ($z = 0; $z < count($groups2); $z++)
        {
            if ($groups2[$z] != "")
            {
                $output .= $groups2[$z] . convertGroup(11 - $z) . (
                        $z < 11
                        && !array_search('', array_slice($groups2, $z + 1, -1))
                        && $groups2[11] != ''
                        && $groups[11]{0} == '0'
                            ? " and "
                            : ", "
                    );
            }
        }

        $output = rtrim($output, ", ");
    }

    if ($fraction > 0)
    {
        $output .= " point";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fraction); $i++)
        {
            $output .= " " . convertDigit($fraction{$i});
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

function convertGroup($index)
{
    switch ($index)
    {
        case 11:
            return " decillion";
        case 10:
            return " nonillion";
        case 9:
            return " octillion";
        case 8:
            return " septillion";
        case 7:
            return " sextillion";
        case 6:
            return " quintrillion";
        case 5:
            return " quadrillion";
        case 4:
            return " trillion";
        case 3:
            return " billion";
        case 2:
            return " million";
        case 1:
            return " thousand";
        case 0:
            return "";
    }
}

function convertThreeDigit($digit1, $digit2, $digit3)
{
    $buffer = "";

    if ($digit1 == "0" && $digit2 == "0" && $digit3 == "0")
    {
        return "";
    }

    if ($digit1 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit1) . " hundred";
        if ($digit2 != "0" || $digit3 != "0")
        {
            $buffer .= " and ";
        }
    }

    if ($digit2 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertTwoDigit($digit2, $digit3);
    }
    else if ($digit3 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit3);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

function convertTwoDigit($digit1, $digit2)
{
    if ($digit2 == "0")
    {
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "1":
                return "ten";
            case "2":
                return "twenty";
            case "3":
                return "thirty";
            case "4":
                return "forty";
            case "5":
                return "fifty";
            case "6":
                return "sixty";
            case "7":
                return "seventy";
            case "8":
                return "eighty";
            case "9":
                return "ninety";
        }
    } else if ($digit1 == "1")
    {
        switch ($digit2)
        {
            case "1":
                return "eleven";
            case "2":
                return "twelve";
            case "3":
                return "thirteen";
            case "4":
                return "fourteen";
            case "5":
                return "fifteen";
            case "6":
                return "sixteen";
            case "7":
                return "seventeen";
            case "8":
                return "eighteen";
            case "9":
                return "nineteen";
        }
    } else
    {
        $temp = convertDigit($digit2);
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "2":
                return "twenty-$temp";
            case "3":
                return "thirty-$temp";
            case "4":
                return "forty-$temp";
            case "5":
                return "fifty-$temp";
            case "6":
                return "sixty-$temp";
            case "7":
                return "seventy-$temp";
            case "8":
                return "eighty-$temp";
            case "9":
                return "ninety-$temp";
        }
    }
}

function convertDigit($digit)
{
    switch ($digit)
    {
        case "0":
            return "zero";
        case "1":
            return "one";
        case "2":
            return "two";
        case "3":
            return "three";
        case "4":
            return "four";
        case "5":
            return "five";
        case "6":
            return "six";
        case "7":
            return "seven";
        case "8":
            return "eight";
        case "9":
            return "nine";
    }
}

 $num = 500254.89;
 $test = convertNumber($num);

 echo $test;

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181945/convert-money-to-text-in-php

Comment: see this following answer 
[See this answer for indian format][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25967687/1931001

Comment: see this following link [Indian Currency format in words using php ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25967687/1931001

Comment: Very Simple Answer here [Click To go answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967530/convert-number-to-words-in-currency-format-india)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [PEAR library](http://pear.php.net/package/Numbers_Words) that can do this.

**EDIT**

Or you can, at the end of your code, do this

```
echo $test . ' cents';
```

Answer (score 7):

indian version

```
function convert_number_to_words($number) {

    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' and ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'negative ';
    $decimal     = ' point ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'one',
        2                   => 'two',
        3                   => 'three',
        4                   => 'four',
        5                   => 'five',
        6                   => 'six',
        7                   => 'seven',
        8                   => 'eight',
        9                   => 'nine',
        10                  => 'ten',
        11                  => 'eleven',
        12                  => 'twelve',
        13                  => 'thirteen',
        14                  => 'fourteen',
        15                  => 'fifteen',
        16                  => 'sixteen',
        17                  => 'seventeen',
        18                  => 'eighteen',
        19                  => 'nineteen',
        20                  => 'twenty',
        30                  => 'thirty',
        40                  => 'fourty',
        50                  => 'fifty',
        60                  => 'sixty',
        70                  => 'seventy',
        80                  => 'eighty',
        90                  => 'ninety',
        100                 => 'hundred',
        1000                => 'thousand',
        100000             => 'lakh',
        10000000          => 'crore'
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . $this->convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        case $number < 100000:
            $thousands   = ((int) ($number / 1000));
            $remainder = $number % 1000;

            $thousands = $this->convert_number_to_words($thousands);

            $string .= $thousands . ' ' . $dictionary[1000];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $separator . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        case $number < 10000000:
            $lakhs   = ((int) ($number / 100000));
            $remainder = $number % 100000;

            $lakhs = $this->convert_number_to_words($lakhs);

            $string = $lakhs . ' ' . $dictionary[100000];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $separator . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000000000:
            $crores   = ((int) ($number / 10000000));
            $remainder = $number % 10000000;

            $crores = $this->convert_number_to_words($crores);

            $string = $crores . ' ' . $dictionary[10000000];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $separator . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string = $this->convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php function numtowords($num){ 
$decones = array( 
            '01' => "One", 
            '02' => "Two", 
            '03' => "Three", 
            '04' => "Four", 
            '05' => "Five", 
            '06' => "Six", 
            '07' => "Seven", 
            '08' => "Eight", 
            '09' => "Nine", 
            10 => "Ten", 
            11 => "Eleven", 
            12 => "Twelve", 
            13 => "Thirteen", 
            14 => "Fourteen", 
            15 => "Fifteen", 
            16 => "Sixteen", 
            17 => "Seventeen", 
            18 => "Eighteen", 
            19 => "Nineteen" 
            );
$ones = array( 
            0 => " ",
            1 => "One",     
            2 => "Two", 
            3 => "Three", 
            4 => "Four", 
            5 => "Five", 
            6 => "Six", 
            7 => "Seven", 
            8 => "Eight", 
            9 => "Nine", 
            10 => "Ten", 
            11 => "Eleven", 
            12 => "Twelve", 
            13 => "Thirteen", 
            14 => "Fourteen", 
            15 => "Fifteen", 
            16 => "Sixteen", 
            17 => "Seventeen", 
            18 => "Eighteen", 
            19 => "Nineteen" 
            ); 
$tens = array( 
            0 => "",
            2 => "Twenty", 
            3 => "Thirty", 
            4 => "Forty", 
            5 => "Fifty", 
            6 => "Sixty", 
            7 => "Seventy", 
            8 => "Eighty", 
            9 => "Ninety" 
            ); 
$hundreds = array( 
            "Hundred", 
            "Thousand", 
            "Million", 
            "Billion", 
            "Trillion", 
            "Quadrillion" 
            ); //limit t quadrillion 
$num = number_format($num,2,".",","); 
$num_arr = explode(".",$num); 
$wholenum = $num_arr[0]; 
$decnum = $num_arr[1]; 
$whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",",$wholenum)); 
krsort($whole_arr); 
$rettxt = ""; 
foreach($whole_arr as $key => $i){ 
    if($i < 20){ 
        $rettxt .= $ones[$i]; 
    }
    elseif($i < 100){ 
        $rettxt .= $tens[substr($i,0,1)]; 
        $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,1,1)]; 
    }
    else{ 
        $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i,0,1)]." ".$hundreds[0]; 
        $rettxt .= " ".$tens[substr($i,1,1)]; 
        $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,2,1)]; 
    } 
    if($key > 0){ 
        $rettxt .= " ".$hundreds[$key]." "; 
    } 

} 
$rettxt = $rettxt." peso/s";

if($decnum > 0){ 
    $rettxt .= " and "; 
    if($decnum < 20){ 
        $rettxt .= $decones[$decnum]; 
    }
    elseif($decnum < 100){ 
        $rettxt .= $tens[substr($decnum,0,1)]; 
        $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($decnum,1,1)]; 
    }
    $rettxt = $rettxt." centavo/s"; 
} 
return $rettxt;} ?>
```

you can use this by

```
echo numtowords(156.50);
```

output is

```
One Hundred Fifty Six peso/s and Fifty centavo/s only.
```

Credit to the owner: Alex Culango
PS: i've edited some lines because it has some error when the tens have "0" and also for proper decimal conversion to words and the peso and centavo placement.

Comment: I tried this with 111.70 and it returned an undefined offset error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about cents but I have created code for Indian Rupees.

```
<?php

echo getIndianCurrency(2851.05);


function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
{
    $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
    $decimal_part = $decimal;
    $hundred = null;
    $hundreds = null;
    $digits_length = strlen($no);
    $decimal_length = strlen($decimal);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $str2 = array();
    $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
        10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve',
        13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen',
        16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen',
        19 => 'nineteen', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty',
        40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty',
        70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'hundred','thousand','lakh', 'crore');

    while( $i < $digits_length ) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($no % $divider);
        $no = floor($no / $divider);
        $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str[] = null;
    }

    $d = 0;
    while( $d < $decimal_length ) {
        $divider = ($d == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $decimal_number = floor($decimal % $divider);
        $decimal = floor($decimal / $divider);
        $d += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($decimal_number) {
            $plurals = (($counter = count($str2)) && $decimal_number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundreds = ($counter == 1 && $str2[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            @$str2 [] = ($decimal_number < 21) ? $words[$decimal_number].' '. $digits[$decimal_number]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($decimal_number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$decimal_number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str2[] = null;
    }

    $Rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
    $paise = implode('', array_reverse($str2));
    $paise = ($decimal_part > 0) ? $paise . ' Paise' : '';
    return ($Rupees ? $Rupees . 'Rupees ' : '') . $paise;
}
?>
```

Output:

**two thousand eight hundred  and fifty one  Rupees five   Paise**

I will write a post about its code description on [guptatreepoint.com](https://www.guptatreepoint.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to edit the function, a quick and dirty way you can do this is by hacking the parts where it prints the words, like this: http://pastebin.com/UwSR8NpV It should work like the way you wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using is fine .

For

```
2143.45
```

I think the output should be :

```
two thousand one hundred forty three and four five cents
```

And not :

```
two thousand one hundred forty three and forty five cents
```

But if you would like it that way , you can still use the function you are using .
 Definitely a longer way of achieving it !!! :

```
$testNumber = '2143.45';

$tempNum = explode( '.' , $testNumber );

$convertedNumber = ( isset( $tempNum[0] ) ? convertNumber( $tempNum[0] ) : '' );

//  Use the below line if you don't want 'and' in the number before decimal point
$convertedNumber = str_replace( ' and ' ,' ' ,$convertedNumber );

//  In the below line if you want you can replace ' and ' with ' , '
$convertedNumber .= ( ( isset( $tempNum[0] ) and isset( $tempNum[1] ) )  ? ' and ' : '' );

$convertedNumber .= ( isset( $tempNum[1] ) ? convertNumber( $tempNum[1] ) .' cents' : '' );

echo $convertedNumber;
```

Displays :

> two thousand, one hundred forty-three and forty-five cents

You can also incorporate the above code lines in to your `converNumber` function where it is translating the faction part `if ($fraction > 0){ }` .

Answer (score 1):

```
For Indian Currnecy 
For Indian Currency
<html>
<head>
<title> Number to word converter</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$ones =array('',' One',' Two',' Three',' Four',' Five',' Six',' Seven',' Eight',' Nine',' Ten',' Eleven',' Twelve',' Thirteen',' Fourteen',' Fifteen',' Sixteen',' Seventeen',' Eighteen',' Nineteen');
$tens = array('','',' Twenty',' Thirty',' Fourty',' Fifty',' Sixty',' Seventy',' Eighty',' Ninety',);
$triplets = array('',' Thousand',' Lac',' Crore',' Arab',' Kharab');


function Show_Amount_In_Words($num) {
  global $ones, $tens, $triplets;
$str ="";


//$num =(int)$num;
$th= (int)($num/1000); 
$x = (int)($num/100) %10;
$fo= explode('.',$num);

if($fo[0] !=null){
$y=(int) substr($fo[0],-2);

}else{
    $y=0;
}

if($x > 0){
    $str =$ones[$x].' Hundred';

}
if($y>0){
if($y<20)
{
 $str .=$ones[$y];

}
else {
    $str .=$tens[($y/10)].$ones[($y%10)];
   }
}
$tri=1;
while($th!=0){

    $lk = $th%100;
    $th = (int)($th/100);
    $count =$tri;

    if($lk<20){
        if($lk == 0){
        $tri =0;}
        $str = $ones[$lk].$triplets[$tri].$str;
        $tri=$count;
        $tri++;
    }else{
        $str = $tens[$lk/10].$ones[$lk%10].$triplets[$tri].$str;
        $tri++;
    }
}
$num =(float)$num;
if(is_float($num)){
     $fo= (String) $num;
      $fo= explode('.',$fo);
       $fo1= @$fo[1];

}else{
    $fo1 =0;
}
$check = (int) $num;
 if($check !=0){
          return $str.' Rupees'.forDecimal($fo1);
    }else{
       return forDecimal($fo1);
    }
}//End function Show_Amount_In_Words

if(isset($_POST['num'])){
   $num = $_POST['num'];
 echo Show_Amount_In_Words($num);
 }



//function for decimal parts
 function forDecimal($num){
    global $ones,$tens;
    $str="";
    $len = strlen($num);
    if($len==1){
        $num=$num*10;
    }
    $x= $num%100;
    if($x>0){
    if($x<20){
        $str = $ones[$x].' Paise';
    }else{
        $str = $tens[$x/10].$ones[$x%10].' Paise';
    }
    }
     return $str;
 }  
?>
<form action='#' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='num' size='20'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation also. Not just code.

Comment: This code for (Indian currency)  Amount convert into the Word.In this program i make two function one for the integer value and another for float value. But here need to call only one function, (Show_Amount_In_Words).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['price']);
$adprice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['adprice']);
$number = $price-$adprice;

$no = round($number);
$point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
$hundred = null;
$digits_1 = strlen($no);
$i = 0;
$str = array();
$words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'One', '2' => 'Two',
    '3' => 'Three', '4' => 'Four', '5' => 'Five', '6' => 'Six',
    '7' => 'Seven', '8' => 'Eight', '9' => 'Nine',
    '10' => 'Ten', '11' => 'Eleven', '12' => 'Twelve',
    '13' => 'Thirteen', '14' => 'Fourteen',
    '15' => 'Fifteen', '16' => 'Sixteen', '17' => 'Seventeen',
    '18' => 'Eighteen', '19' =>'Nineteen', '20' => 'Twenty',
    '30' => 'Thirty', '40' => 'Forty', '50' => 'Fifty',
    '60' => 'Sixty', '70' => 'Seventy',
    '80' => 'Eighty', '90' => 'Ninety');
$digits = array('', 'Hundred', 'Thousand', 'Lakh', 'Crore');
while ($i < $digits_1) {
$divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
$number = floor($no % $divider);
$no = floor($no / $divider);
$i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;
if ($number) {
    $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
    $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
    $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
                " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
                :
                $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
                . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
                . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
            } else $str[] = null;
              }
$str = array_reverse($str);
$result = implode('', $str);
$points = ($point) ?
          "." . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
          echo $result . "  " . $points . "Only ";
 ?>
```

Comment: We certainly shouldn't be seeing `mysqli_real_escape_string` anywhere in this unexplained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved this problem using `php`

See this following link [Stackoverflow Best Conversion Result for Indian Currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967530/convert-number-to-words-in-currency-format-india)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add something for the decimal value.  Hope it will help.

```
<?php
function convertNumber($number)
{
    list($integer,$fraction) = explode(".", (string) $number);

    $output = " ";

    if ($integer{0} == "-")
    {
        $output = "negative ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "-");
    }
    else if ($integer{0} == "+")
    {
        $output = "positive ";
        $integer    = ltrim($integer, "+");
    }

    if ($integer{0} == "0")
    {
        $output .= "zero";
    }
    else
    {
        $integer = str_pad($integer, 36, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $group   = rtrim(chunk_split($integer, 3, " "), " ");
        $groups  = explode(" ", $group);

        $groups2 = array();
        foreach ($groups as $g)
        {
            $groups2[] = convertThreeDigit($g{0}, $g{1}, $g{2});
        }

        for ($z = 0; $z < count($groups2); $z++)
        {
            if ($groups2[$z] != "")
            {
                $output .= $groups2[$z] . convertGroup(11 - $z) . (
                        $z < 11
                        && !array_search('', array_slice($groups2, $z + 1, -1))
                        && $groups2[11] != ''
                        && $groups[11]{0} == '0'
                            ? " and "
                            : " "
                    );
            }
        }

        $output = rtrim($output, ", ");
    }

    if ($fraction > 0)
    {
        $output .= " PESOS ";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fraction); $i++)
        {
           if($fraction==01){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and one centavo only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==02){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and two centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==03){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and three centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==04){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and four centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==05){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and five centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==06){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and six centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==07){

              $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " point seven centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==8 || $fraction==08){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                 $output .= " and eight centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==9 || $fraction==09){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                 $output .= " and nine centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==10){

                  $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                  $output .= " and ten centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==11){

              $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and eleven centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
             else if($fraction==12){

                 $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and twelve centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==13){

             $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and thirteen centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==14){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and fourteen centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==15){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and fifteen centavos only";

                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==16){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and sixteen centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==17){


               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventeen centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==18){


               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                $output .= " and eighteen centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==19){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and nineteen centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction==20){

               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and twenty centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==21){
               $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                  $output .= " and twenty one centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==22){

              $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and twenty two centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==23){
                 $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                         $output .= " and twenty three centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==24){

                 $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and twenty four centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==25){

             $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                 $output .= " and twenty five centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==26){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                    $output .= " and twenty six centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==27){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                 $output .= " and twenty seven centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==28){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                    $output .= " and twenty eight centavos only";
                 $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction==29){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and twenty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
             else if($fraction ==30){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==31){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==32){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==33){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==34){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==35){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
             else if($fraction ==36){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==37){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==38){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==39){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and thirty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==40){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==41){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==42){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==43){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==44){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==45){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==46){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==47){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==48){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==49){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fourty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==50){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==51){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==52){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==53){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==54){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==55){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==56){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==57){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==58){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==59){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and fifty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==60){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
          else if($fraction ==61){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==62){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==63){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==64){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
          else if($fraction ==65){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
         else if($fraction ==66){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }

         else if($fraction ==67){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
        else if($fraction ==68){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
        else if($fraction ==69){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and sixty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
       else if($fraction ==70){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
     else if($fraction ==71){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }

     else if($fraction ==72){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
    else if($fraction ==73){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
     else if($fraction ==74){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }

            else if($fraction ==75){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==76){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==77){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==78){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==79){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and seventy nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
            else if($fraction ==80){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
         else if($fraction ==81){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
        else if($fraction ==82){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
       else if($fraction ==83){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
      else if($fraction ==84){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
        else if($fraction ==85){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
         else if($fraction ==86){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==87){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==88){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==89){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and eighty nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==90){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==91){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety one centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==92){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety two centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==93){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety three centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==94){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety four centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==95){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety five centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==96){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety six centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==97){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety seven centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==98){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety eight centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }
           else if($fraction ==99){

                $i = 1;
                while ($i <2):
                     $output .= " and ninety nine centavos only";
                    $i++;
                endwhile;
           }

        }

    }
      else{
            $output .= " PESOS ONLY";
           }

    return $output;
}

function convertGroup($index)
{
    switch ($index)
    {
        case 11:
            return " decillion";
        case 10:
            return " nonillion";
        case 9:
            return " octillion";
        case 8:
            return " septillion";
        case 7:
            return " sextillion";
        case 6:
            return " quintrillion";
        case 5:
            return " quadrillion";
        case 4:
            return " trillion";
        case 3:
            return " billion";
        case 2:
            return " million";
        case 1:
            return " thousand";
        case 0:
            return "";
    }
}

function convertThreeDigit($digit1, $digit2, $digit3)
{
    $buffer = " ";

    if ($digit1 == "0" && $digit2 == "0" && $digit3 == "0")
    {
        return "";
    }

    if ($digit1 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit1) . " hundred";
        if ($digit2 != "0" || $digit3 != "0")
        {
            $buffer .= " ";
        }
    }

    if ($digit2 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertTwoDigit($digit2, $digit3);
    }
    else if ($digit3 != "0")
    {
        $buffer .= convertDigit($digit3);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

function convertTwoDigit($digit1, $digit2)
{
    if ($digit2 == "0")
    {
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "1":
                return "ten";
            case "2":
                return "twenty";
            case "3":
                return "thirty";
            case "4":
                return "forty";
            case "5":
                return "fifty";
            case "6":
                return "sixty";
            case "7":
                return "seventy";
            case "8":
                return "eighty";
            case "9":
                return "ninety";
        }
    } else if ($digit1 == "1")
    {
        switch ($digit2)
        {
            case "1":
                return "eleven";
            case "2":
                return "twelve";
            case "3":
                return "thirteen";
            case "4":
                return "fourteen";
            case "5":
                return "fifteen";
            case "6":
                return "sixteen";
            case "7":
                return "seventeen";
            case "8":
                return "eighteen";
            case "9":
                return "nineteen";
        }
    } else
    {
        $temp = convertDigit($digit2);
        switch ($digit1)
        {
            case "2":
                return "twenty $temp";
            case "3":
                return "thirty $temp";
            case "4":
                return "forty $temp";
            case "5":
                return "fifty $temp";
            case "6":
                return "sixty $temp";
            case "7":
                return "seventy $temp";
            case "8":
                return "eighty $temp";
            case "9":
                return "ninety $temp";
        }
    }
}

function convertDigit($digit)
{
    switch ($digit)
    {
        case "0":
            return "zero";
        case "1":
            return "one";
        case "2":
            return "two";
        case "3":
            return "three";
        case "4":
            return "four";
        case "5":
            return "five";
        case "6":
            return "six";
        case "7":
            return "seven";
        case "8":
            return "eight";
        case "9":
            return "nine";
    }

}
strtoupper(convertNumber(2143.45)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// three hundred and thirteen rupees and seventy-six paise
echo getIndianCurrency(313.76);

function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
{
    $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
    $hundred = null;
    $digits_length = strlen($no);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
        10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve',
        13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen',
        16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen',
        19 => 'nineteen', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty',
        40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty',
        70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'hundred','thousand','lakh', 'crore');

    while( $i < $digits_length ) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($no % $divider);
        $no = floor($no / $divider);
        $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
        } else $str[] = null;
    }

    $rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
    $paise = '';

    if ($decimal) {
        $paise = 'and ';
        $decimal_length = strlen($decimal);

        if ($decimal_length == 2) {
            if ($decimal >= 20) {
                $dc = $decimal % 10;
                $td = $decimal - $dc;
                $ps = ($dc == 0) ? '' : '-' . $words[$dc];

                $paise .= $words[$td] . $ps;
            } else {
                $paise .= $words[$decimal];
            }
        } else {
            $paise .= $words[$decimal % 10];
        }

        $paise .= ' paise';
    }

    return ($rupees ? $rupees . 'rupees ' : '') . $paise ;
}
```

Uses:

```
echo getIndianCurrency(313.76);
```

Output:

```
three hundred and thirteen rupees and seventy-six paise
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is helpful to get the output for Dollar...**

```
$word = numberTowords(100045.95);
echo $word;
exit();

function numberTowords($num)
{

    $ones = array(
        0 =>"ZERO",
        1 => "ONE",
        2 => "TWO",
        3 => "THREE",
        4 => "FOUR",
        5 => "FIVE",
        6 => "SIX",
        7 => "SEVEN",
        8 => "EIGHT",
        9 => "NINE",
        10 => "TEN",
        11 => "ELEVEN",
        12 => "TWELVE",
        13 => "THIRTEEN",
        14 => "FOURTEEN",
        15 => "FIFTEEN",
        16 => "SIXTEEN",
        17 => "SEVENTEEN",
        18 => "EIGHTEEN",
        19 => "NINETEEN"
    );

    $tens = array( 
        0 => "ZERO",
        1 => "TEN",
        2 => "TWENTY",
        3 => "THIRTY", 
        4 => "FORTY", 
        5 => "FIFTY", 
        6 => "SIXTY", 
        7 => "SEVENTY", 
        8 => "EIGHTY", 
        9 => "NINETY" 
    ); 

    $hundreds = array( 
        "HUNDRED", 
        "THOUSAND", 
        "MILLION", 
        "BILLION", 
        "TRILLION", 
        "QUARDRILLION" 
    ); /*limit t quadrillion */

    $num = number_format($num,2,".",","); 
    $num_arr = explode(".",$num); 
    $wholenum = $num_arr[0]; 
    $decnum = $num_arr[1]; 

    $whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",",$wholenum)); 
    krsort($whole_arr,1); 

    $rettxt = ""; 
    foreach($whole_arr as $key => $i){
      
        while(substr($i,0,1)=="0")
            $i=substr($i,1,5);
        if($i < 20){ 
            /* echo "getting:".$i; */
            $rettxt .= $ones[$i]; 
        }elseif($i < 100){ 
            if(substr($i,0,1)!="0")  $rettxt .= $tens[substr($i,0,1)]; 
            if(substr($i,1,1)!="0") $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,1,1)]; 
        } else{ 
             if(substr($i,0,1)!="0") $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i,0,1)]." ".$hundreds[0]; 
            if(substr($i,1,1)!="0")$rettxt .= " ".$tens[substr($i,1,1)]; 
            if(substr($i,2,1)!="0")$rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($i,2,1)]; 
        } 
        if($key > 0){ 
            $rettxt .= " ".$hundreds[$key]." "; 
        }
    } 
    if($decnum > 0){
        $rettxt .= " AND ";
        if($decnum < 20) {
            $rettxt .= $ones[$decnum]." FILS";
        } elseif($decnum < 100) {
            $rettxt .= $tens[substr($decnum,0,1)];
            $rettxt .= " ".$ones[substr($decnum,1,1)]. " FILS";
        }
    }
    return $rettxt;
}
```

> The output is : ONE HUNDRED THOUSAND FORTY FIVE AND NINETY FIVE FILS

Answer (score 0):

For Dollar Conversion,

```
  public static function getWords($number = false)
{
    $hyphen = ' ';
    $conjunction = ' ';
    $separator = ', ';
    $negative = 'negative ';
    $decimal = ' And ';
    $dictionary = array(
        0 => 'zero',
        1 => 'one',
        2 => 'two',
        3 => 'three',
        4 => 'four',
        5 => 'five',
        6 => 'six',
        7 => 'seven',
        8 => 'eight',
        9 => 'nine',
        10 => 'ten',
        11 => 'eleven',
        12 => 'twelve',
        13 => 'thirteen',
        14 => 'fourteen',
        15 => 'fifteen',
        16 => 'sixteen',
        17 => 'seventeen',
        18 => 'eighteen',
        19 => 'nineteen',
        20 => 'twenty',
        30 => 'thirty',
        40 => 'fourty',
        50 => 'fifty',
        60 => 'sixty',
        70 => 'seventy',
        80 => 'eighty',
        90 => 'ninety',
        100 => 'hundred',
        1000 => 'thousand',
        1000000 => 'million',
        1000000000 => 'billion',
        1000000000000 => 'trillion',
        1000000000000000 => 'quadrillion',
        1000000000000000000 => 'quintillion'
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words only accepts numbers between -' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' and ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . PoMaster::getWords(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;


    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string .= $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units = $number % 10;
            $string .= $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds = $number / 100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string .= $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . PoMaster::getWords($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            $string .= PoMaster::getWords($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= PoMaster::getWords($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }
    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction) && $fraction != '00') {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
        $string .= ' Halals ';
    }

    return ucwords($string);
}
```

You can Replace the currency in `$string` variable at end.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question, but there's a simple way to get this using [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```php
function currencyLabels(string $locale)
{
  return [
    "en_US" => ["US Dollars", "cents"],
    "en_IN" => ["Indian Rupees", "paise"]
  ][$locale];
}

function amountInWords(float $amount, string $locale = "en_US")
{
  $hasDecimal = fmod($amount, 1) !== 0.0;
  $currencyLabels = currencyLabels($locale);
  $words = "$currencyLabels[0] ";
  $formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

  if (!$hasDecimal) {
    $words .= ucwords(
      str_replace(
        "-",
        " ",
        $formatter->format($amount, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY)
      )
    );
    return $words;
  }
  
  [$dollars, $cents] = explode(".", $amount);
  $words .= ucwords(
    str_replace(
      "-",
      " ",
      $formatter->format($dollars, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY)
    )
  );
  $words .= " and ";
  $words .= ucwords($formatter->format($cents, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY));
  $words .= " $currencyLabels[1]";

  return $words;
}
```

Then using this function with locales supported by NumberFormatter class, we can get the desired output

```php
amountInWords(2143.95);

//Will output: US Dollars Two Thousand One Hundred Forty Three and Ninety-five cents
```

**Note:** We will have to update the `currencyLabels` function to include whichever locales we need to support.

Answer (score -1):

Money format (India - Rupee) (Working upto 13 digits)

Here i convert number into word format(Currency)

Ex : if you enter 1011, then you will get answer: One Thousand Eleven Rupee

Using string and array function and control structure(if)

```
    // Ex: num = 1250.75

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["num"])) {

       // Getting number before(".")
        $num = $_POST["num"];  // $num = 1250.75
        $num_length = strcspn($num, "."); // length of $num
        $new_num = substr($num, 0, $num_length); // $new_num = 1250
        $new_num = (double) $new_num; // this will remove zero like 0001 = 1 
        $length = strlen($new_num); // length of $new_num

       //Getting number after(".")
        $num2 = strchr($num, "."); // $num2 = .75

        $num2_length = strlen($num2); // length of $num2
        $new_num2 = substr($num2, 1, 3); // This'll give you only '75' from '.75'
        $new_num2 = (double) $new_num2; // remove zero like '05' equals to '5'
        $precision_len = strlen($new_num2); // length of $new_num2

    //Declare global variable
        global $result; // to store result of 1250
        global $result2; // to store result of 75


    // Check length of input and call appropriate function

        if ($length == 1) {
            if ($new_num == 0 && $new_num2 == NULL) {
                $result = "Zero Rupee";
            } else {
                $result = singleDigitWord($new_num) . " Rupee";
            }
            //echo $res;
        } elseif ($length == 2) {
            $result = twoDigitWord($new_num) . " Rupee";
            //echo $res;
        } elseif ($length == 3) {
            $result = threeDigitWord($new_num) . " Rupee";
            //echo $res;
        } elseif ($length == 4 || $length == 5) {
            $result = fourOrFiveDigitWord($length, $new_num) . " Rupee";
        } elseif ($length == 6 || $length == 7) {
            $result = sixOrSevenDigitWord($length, $new_num) . " Rupee";
        } elseif ($length == 8 || $length == 9) {
            $result = eightOrNineDigitWord($length, $new_num) . " Rupee";
        } elseif ($length == 10 || $length == 11) {
            $result = tenOrElevenDigitWord($length, $new_num) . " Rupee";
        } elseif ($length == 12 || $length == 13) {
            $result = twelveOrThirteenDigitWord($length, $new_num) . " Rupee";
        }

        if ($new_num2 > 0) {
            if ($precision_len == 1) {
                $result2 = singleDigitWord($new_num2) . " Paisa";
            } elseif ($precision_len == 2) {
                $result2 = twoDigitWord($new_num2) . " Paisa";
            }
        }
    }

 // Array containing value 1 to 9
    function singleDigitWord($a)
    {
        $array = [
            "1" => "One",
            "2" => "Two",
            "3" => "Three",
            "4" => "Four",
            "5" => "Five",
            "6" => "Six",
            "7" => "Seven",
            "8" => "Eight",
            "9" => "Nine",
        ];
        if (array_key_exists((int) $a, $array)) {
            return $array[$a];
        }
    }


// Array containing value 10 to 19
    function ten2nineteen($a)
    {
        $array = [
            "10" => "Ten",
            "11" => "Eleven",
            "12" => "Twelve",
            "13" => "Thirteen",
            "14" => "Fourteen",
            "15" => "Fifteen",
            "16" => "Sixteen",
            "17" => "Seventeen",
            "18" => "Eighteen",
            "19" => "Nineteen",
        ];
        if (array_key_exists((int) $a, $array)) {
            return $array[$a];
        }
    }

// if length is 2,then 10 to 99 digits conversion
    function twoDigitWord($a)
    {
        if ($a >= 10 && $a <= 19) {
            $output = ten2nineteen($a);
            return $output;
        } elseif ($a >= 20 && $a <= 29) {
            if ($a == 20) {
                return "Twenty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 20;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Twenty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 30 && $a <= 39) {
            if ($a == 30) {
                return "Thirty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 30;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Thirty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 40 && $a <= 49) {
            if ($a == 40) {
                return "Forty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 40;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Forty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 50 && $a <= 59) {
            if ($a == 50) {
                return "Fifty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 50;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Fifty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 60 && $a <= 69) {
            if ($a == 60) {
                return "Sixty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 60;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Sixty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 70 && $a <= 79) {
            if ($a == 70) {
                return "Seventy";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 70;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Seventy " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 80 && $a <= 89) {
            if ($a == 80) {
                return "Eighty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 80;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Eighty " . $y;
            }
        } elseif ($a >= 90 && $a <= 99) {
            if ($a == 90) {
                return "Ninty";
            } else {
                $a = $a - 90;
                $y = singleDigitWord($a);
                return "Ninty " . $y;
            }
        }
    }

// if length is 3,then 100 to 999 digits conversion
    function threeDigitWord($a)
    {

        $output = str_split($a);
        $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -2);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Hundred " . $second;
    }

// if length is 4 or 5,then 1000 to 99999 digits conversion
    function fourOrFiveDigitWord($length, $a)
    {
        if ($length == 4) {
            $output = str_split($a);
            $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        } elseif ($length == 5) {
            $output = str_split($a, 2);
            $first = twoDigitWord($output[0]);
        }
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -3);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Thousand " . $second;
    }

// if length is 6 or 7,then 100000 to 9999999 digits conversion
    function sixOrSevenDigitWord($length, $a)
    {
        if ($length == 6) {
            $output = str_split($a);
            $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        } elseif ($length == 7) {
            $output = str_split($a, 2);
            $first = twoDigitWord($output[0]);
        }
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -5);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Lakh " . $second;
    }

// if length is 8 or 9,then 10000000 to 999999999 digits conversion
    function eightOrNineDigitWord($length, $a)
    {
        if ($length == 8) {
            $output = str_split($a);
            $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        } elseif ($length == 9) {
            $output = str_split($a, 2);
            $first = twoDigitWord($output[0]);
        }
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -7);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Crore " . $second;
    }

// if length is 10 or 11,then 1000000000 to 99999999999 digits conversion
    function tenOrElevenDigitWord($length, $a)
    {
        if ($length == 10) {
            $output = str_split($a);
            $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        } elseif ($length == 11) {
            $output = str_split($a, 2);
            $first = twoDigitWord($output[0]);
        }
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -9);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Billion " . $second;
    }

// if length is 12 or 13,then 100000000000 to 99999999999999 digits conversion
    function twelveOrThirteenDigitWord($length, $a)
    {
        if ($length == 12) {
            $output = str_split($a);
            $first = singleDigitWord($output[0]);
        } elseif ($length == 13) {
            $output = str_split($a, 2);
            $first = twoDigitWord($output[0]);
        }
        $lastdigits = substr($a, -11);
        $lastdigits = (double) $lastdigits;
        $second = lastDigitWord($lastdigits);
        return $first . " Trillion " . $second;
    }


// this function gets value of $lastdigits which is declared in function above 
// like twelveOrThirteenDigitWord or many other 
// Ex: if your num is 1111 then your last digit will be 111 and you'll get 
// answer by calling this function. lastDigitWords function call one of above 
// function but i declare it here beacause we do not need to write it in every 
// function above to get conversion of $lastdigits

    function lastDigitWord($a)
    {
        if ($a <= 9) {
            return singleDigitWord($a);
        } elseif ($a >= 10 && $a <= 99) {
            return twoDigitWord($a);
        } elseif ($a >= 100 && $a <= 999) {
            return threeDigitWord($a);
        } elseif ($a >= 1000 && $a <= 99999) {
            $new_length = strlen($a);
            return fourORFiveDigitWord($new_length, $a);
        } elseif ($a >= 100000 && $a <= 9999999) {
            $new_length = strlen($a);
            return sixORSevenDigitWord($new_length, $a);
        } elseif ($a >= 10000000 && $a <= 999999999) {
            $new_length = strlen($a);
            return eightOrNineDigitWord($new_length, $a);
        } elseif ($a >= 1000000000 && $a <= 99999999999) {
            $new_length = strlen($a);
            return tenOrElevenDigitWord($new_length, $a);
        }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form name="myForm" method="POST" action="">
                <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="num">Enter Number: </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="num" id="num" value="<?php
                            if (isset($_POST['num'])) {
                                echo $_POST['num'];
                            }
                            ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <p><b>In words : </b>
                <?php
                global $result;
                global $result2;
                echo $result . " " . $result2;
                ?>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks for suggestion @Toby Speigh. And check out comments in program and short description above **after update**