# Convert Number to Words in Indian currency format with paise value

Tags: php, currency, currency-formatting

**Using PHP how to convert number to Indian currency word format with paise (decimal value)**

**Input**
`190908100.25`

**Output we need**

```
nineteen crores nine lakh eight thousand one hundred Rupees .two five Paise
```

I expect this conversion method in core `php` .

Comment: Write your own function?

Comment: calculate each char define it's value?

Comment: this link might be useful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308102/how-to-convert-decimal-number-to-words-money-format-using-php

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Convert Currency Number to Word Format Using `PHP`**

```
 <?php
  /**
   * Created by PhpStorm.
   * User: sakthikarthi
   * Date: 9/22/14
   * Time: 11:26 AM
   * Converting Currency Numbers to words currency format
   */
$number = 190908100.25;
   $no = floor($number);
   $point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
   $hundred = null;
   $digits_1 = strlen($no);
   $i = 0;
   $str = array();
   $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
    '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
    '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
    '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
    '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
    '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
    '18' => 'eighteen', '19' =>'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
    '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
    '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
    '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
   $digits = array('', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');
   while ($i < $digits_1) {
     $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
     $number = floor($no % $divider);
     $no = floor($no / $divider);
     $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;
     if ($number) {
        $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
        $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
        $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
            " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred
            :
            $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
            . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
            . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
     } else $str[] = null;
  }
  $str = array_reverse($str);
  $result = implode('', $str);
  $points = ($point) ?
    "." . $words[$point / 10] . " " . 
          $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';
  echo $result . "Rupees  " . $points . " Paise";
 ?>
```

- Output

  **nineteen crores nine lakh eight thousand one hundred Rupees . two five Paise**

  ---

  Now i have added Simplified Method as follows:

  function getIndianCurrency(float $number)
  {
      $decimal = round($number - ($no = floor($number)), 2) * 100;
      $hundred = null;
      $digits_length = strlen($no);
      $i = 0;
      $str = array();
      $words = array(0 => '', 1 => 'one', 2 => 'two',
          3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six',
          7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
          10 => 'ten', 11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve',
          13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen',
          16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen',
          19 => 'nineteen', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty',
          40 => 'forty', 50 => 'fifty', 60 => 'sixty',
          70 => 'seventy', 80 => 'eighty', 90 => 'ninety');
      $digits = array('', 'hundred','thousand','lakh', 'crore');
      while( $i < $digits_length ) {
          $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
          $number = floor($no % $divider);
          $no = floor($no / $divider);
          $i += $divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
          if ($number) {
              $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
              $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? ' and ' : null;
              $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number].' '. $digits[$counter]. $plural.' '.$hundred:$words[floor($number / 10) * 10].' '.$words[$number % 10]. ' '.$digits[$counter].$plural.' '.$hundred;
          } else $str[] = null;
      }
      $Rupees = implode('', array_reverse($str));
      $paise = ($decimal > 0) ? "." . ($words[$decimal / 10] . " " . $words[$decimal % 10]) . ' Paise' : '';
      return ($Rupees ? $Rupees . 'Rupees ' : '') . $paise;
  }

method calling :

`echo getIndianCurrency(79855995.19);`

output 
**seven crore ninety eight lakhs fifty five thousands nine hundred and ninety five Rupees .one nine Paise**

Comment: Perfectly works for me.

Comment: it saves my time. thanks a lot

Comment: `34234.50` this  number returns error ***Notice: Undefined offset: -5***

Comment: share your code logic

Comment: This support upto 99 crores. 100 crore onwards, it returns notice and wrong result.

Comment: Shouldn't it show "twenty-five paisa"? for `190908100.25`

Comment: yes two five paisa is the currency standard

Comment: there is a problem in both cases it's seven paise.
313.70 = three hundred and thirteen rupees and seven paise,
313.07 = three hundred and thirteen rupees and seven paise

Comment: That's great! Thanks for your effort. It saved my time! :)

Comment: Just change 2nd last line to 
$paise = ($decimal > 0) ? "" . ($words[(int)($decimal/10)*10] . " " . $words[$decimal % 10]) . ' Paise' : '';