# how to convert number into word in mpdf?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to convert number into word using mpdf.

```
$sum=1000;
```

in my td tag

```
<td>Rupees . </td> One thousand only
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar function adapted from a previous Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25967687/2469308). It solves some of the edge cases involving decimal currency values. It takes any amount, and converts into Indian Currency format (Lakhs, Crores, Rupees, Paise etc). Find below the function:

```
/**
 * Converting Currency Numbers to words currency indian format
 */
function convert_to_currency_indian_format($amount) {
    if ($amount == 0) {
        return "Zero Rupees Only";
    }
    //$number = 190908100.25;
    $number = round($amount, 2);
    $no = floor($number);
    $point = round($number - $no, 2) * 100;
    $hundred = null;
    $digits_1 = strlen($no);
    $i = 0;
    $str = array();
    $words = array('0' => '', '1' => 'one', '2' => 'two',
        '3' => 'three', '4' => 'four', '5' => 'five', '6' => 'six',
        '7' => 'seven', '8' => 'eight', '9' => 'nine',
        '10' => 'ten', '11' => 'eleven', '12' => 'twelve',
        '13' => 'thirteen', '14' => 'fourteen',
        '15' => 'fifteen', '16' => 'sixteen', '17' => 'seventeen',
        '18' => 'eighteen', '19' => 'nineteen', '20' => 'twenty',
        '30' => 'thirty', '40' => 'forty', '50' => 'fifty',
        '60' => 'sixty', '70' => 'seventy',
        '80' => 'eighty', '90' => 'ninety');
    $digits = array('', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'lakh', 'crore');
    while ($i < $digits_1) {
        $divider = ($i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
        $number = floor($no % $divider);
        $no = floor($no / $divider);
        $i += ($divider == 10) ? 1 : 2;
        if ($number) {
            $plural = (($counter = count($str)) && $number > 9) ? 's' : null;
            $hundred = ($counter == 1 && $str[0]) ? 'and ' : null;
            $str [] = ($number < 21) ? $words[$number] .
                    " " . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred :
                    $words[floor($number / 10) * 10]
                    . " " . $words[$number % 10] . " "
                    . $digits[$counter] . $plural . " " . $hundred;
        } else
            $str[] = null;
    }
    $str = array_reverse($str);
    $result = implode('', $str);

    $points = ($point) ?
            $words[10 * (int) ($point / 10)] . " " .
            $words[$point = $point % 10] : '';

    if (!empty($points)) {
        return ucwords($result) . "Rupees " . ucwords($points) . " Paise Only";
    } else {
        return ucwords($result) . "Rupees Only ";
    }
}
```